# How to apply Cuda.jl on DataFrames in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, gpu, julia-gpu

I am using `dataframes.jl` package in the below mentioned code to perform certain operations.

1. I would like to know, how may I apply `CUDA.jl` on this code, if possible while keeping the dataframe aspect?
2. Secondly, is it possible to allow the code to automatically choose between `CPU` and `GPU` based on the availability?

## Code

```
using DataFrame
df = DataFrame(i = Int64[], a = Float64[], b =Float64[])

for i in 1:10
    push!(df.i, i)

    a = i + sin(i)*cos(i)/sec(i)^100
    push!(df.a, a)

    b = i + tan(i)*cosec(i)/sin(i)
    push!(df.b, b)
end
transform!(df, [:a, :b] .=> (x -> [missing; diff(x)]) .=> [:da, :db])
```

Please suggest a solution to make this code compatible with `CUDA.jl`.

Thanks in advance!!